# Want to compare from one module with another module

Tags: angularjs

```
   angular.module('MyApp')
    //var appVersion = '20171901'

     .constant('API_URL', '/xyz/');

     .config(["checkAppVersion", function(checkAppVersion) {
    checkAppVersion.appVersion='20171203';
     }])
```

This is my app.config file ,Here i want to set app version right now am keeping it manually ,

```
 angular.module(MyApp.user).
controller('appVersionCtrl',function(checkAppVersion){
  //ctrler
   if(user.appversion === checkAppVersion){
          //do something
        }
 }
```

Now i want to check version of user and version i set in myApp is equal  or not
is I did it correctly if not whats the way?

Comment: As long as your primary module depends on other modules, all providers (constants, values, factories, controllers and services) become available by name. They all go into a global pool of sorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your app version in constants

```
angular.module('MyApp')
//var appVersion = '20171901'

   .constant('userconstants', {
    "API_URL": "/xyz/",
    "appVersion": "1.0",
});
```

and in your second module include the first module

```
angular.module('MyApp.user', [
    'ionic',
    'MyApp',
])
```

And then In your controller, you can directly use the constant to compare

```
 .controller('appVersionCtrl', function (userconstants) {
 if(appversion === userconstants.appVersion){
      //do something
    }

}
```